# Compressed hidden files are not hidden anymore when uncompressing on Windows

Tags: macos, windows, zip, compression

When I zip hidden files and folder and unzip on a Windows PC, they do not remain hidden. I tried to hide them with dot and also with the command `chflags hidden`.

Is there anything I can do? It happens only when sending Mac to Windows, Mac to Mac works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filesystem running on macOS and Windows handles hidden files differently. The two approaches, i.e. prepending a dot `.` character to filename or using `chflags hidden` won't work as it will set the file as hidden on Mac and not on Windows.

The filenames prepended with `.` will remain hidden on any UNIX/Linux system.

---

You can hide files on Windows by getting properties on a file and checking the "hidden" box on the general tab. This will only hide a file if you don't change the default behavior of Windows Explorer to keep hidden files hidden.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you Nimesh. Is there anything to keep these files hidden when unzipping on Windows?

Comment: @TryingTrying  no there is not as I think zip files do not contain anything to mark a file as hidden except the file name for Unix.